# SSIS Bulk Insert Task Operating system error code 1311

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, sql-server-agent, bulk-insert

I have been running SSIS 2008 R2 Packages for a long time and when ever my Packages trough SQL Server Job accesses FTP Server which is on the same domain it uses correct credentials ,e.g. `domain\domainuser`. Note: SQL Server is DC and FTP Server is not.

Now when I run `Bulk Insert Task`, which in addition uses a `Format File`, which is located on the same FTP Server, it uses `ftpservername\guest` credentials instead of `domain\domainuser` and throws back an error:

> [Bulk Insert Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message: "Cannot bulk load because the file "\ftpserveripadress\FTP
>   Access\client\From client\a_file_that_exists.txt" could not
>   be opened. Operating system error code 1311(There are currently no
>   logon servers available to service the logon request.).".

I have no clue why this particular task is not using correct credentials, and I had no success finding anything related between `Bulk Insert Task` and `Operating system error code 1311`.

**Note:** If this is not the correct place to post a question like this, please advise me with appropriate place to post this.

Comment: Wait is your package inserting into a file? Can you post some Screenshots of the package?

Comment: @Zane No my package is using Bulk Insert Task, to perform Bulk Insert into one of my tables from a file that I receive daily on FTP Server.

Comment: Alright try disabling your OLEDB/BULK INSERT task and just switch it to a row count. If you still get this error then your problem is with you FTP task and not with your insert.

Comment: @Zane I'll get back to you with results.